# jQuery Box Area Problem

Tags: jquery, area

I have a problem - I have 2 or 3 boxes and I am trying to fit them perfectly into a bigger square box of max-width 445px. All boxes should be sized to fill the bigger box.

I don't know what any of the box widths or heights will be and therefore the second two boxes should be sized relative to the first ? The aspect ratio of the first box can also change [i.e. be long or be wide] and so the second two boxes should fill.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure about the boxes size, including the padding and margin.
i think you can log out the width and height of the inner boxes by user jQuery.outerHeight(), jQuery.outerWidth()